# JS text to speech to android web view text to speech

Tags: javascript, android, webview, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Hello guys i've been working on a website where i'm using Javascript text-to-speech API to play some text and it works great for web browsers but now the project is being ported to android and text-to-speech is not working on it at all.
android's web view is being used by the android developer to open the site in app
For porting from web to android, i have used Mobile detection library fro mobiledetect.net and so i can detect if it's android or not.
since i can detect "if mobile" i was wondering if there is actually a way to place some android code in onclick attribute when it's mobile which will then call android's text-to-speech API else JS function.

the function grabs plain text from a div and passes it to text-to-speech. i was wondering if same could happen using android where by detecting mobile i can place some android code in onclick attribute and android takes care of the rest.

-- here is a code of my javascript text-to-speech --

```
//area_id == div id with text.... btn_id = id of the button which is being clicked
function textToAudio(area_id, btn_id){
    var amISpeaking = window.speechSynthesis.speaking;

    if(amISpeaking){
        var etext = $("#"+btn_id).html();

        if(etext == "Play"){
            window.speechSynthesis.resume();
            $("#"+btn_id).html("Pause");
        }else if(etext == "Pause"){
            window.speechSynthesis.pause();
            $("#"+btn_id).html("Play");
        };

        return false;
    }else{
        $("#"+btn_id).html("Pause");
    };


    /* playing souund */
    var msg = $("#"+area_id).html();
    msg = $.trim(msg);

    if(empty_check(msg) || (msg == NO_VAL)){ msg = "Either there is no text or something went wrong during processing."; };
    
    let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    speech.lang = "en-US";
    
    speech.text = msg;
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
    
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
};
```

anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: Android webview doesn't support speechsynthesis api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis#browser_compatibility Instead you could use something like responsive voice.